# Use a list of product names and their abbreviations in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS. In an application I am extending I have to different kinds of views. I one, I want to see full product names, and in the other only their abbreviations.

I wouldn't like to hard-code them but to write them in a file. What's a good way to accomplish that? I thought about creating an json/xml/text file which would look something like this

```
'product name 1' : 'abbr1'
'product name 2' : 'abbr2'
[...]
```

but I need the result to work in both directions, like either passing an abbreviation and getting the full name or the other way round. I can use javascript and jquery.

Edit: I want not to hard-code the data because the products are subject to change, so I wouldn't really like them to be in the source code. I think stuff like this which can frequently change should be stored outside the source code so it can be changed easier.

Comment: For what purpose, would you like to write it to a file?

Comment: The products are subject to change, so I wouldn't really like them to be in the source code. I think stuff like this which can frequently change should be stored outside the source code so it can be changed easier.

Comment: Is this all client-side JavaScript?

Comment: Sadly I don't know how to answer your question (yet). While I do my reading on this topic, maybe it may answer your question that I am extending an MediaWiki implementation. I have access to the whole source. The instance of MediaWiki was setup by someone else, so I don't know details about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the array of products in a JSON file. Something like:

```
[{name: "Product 1", abbr: "pr1"}, {name: "Product 2", abbr: "pr2}...]
```

Then you could use [jQuery's getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method as such:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( json ) {
    // do something with the json
});
```

However, that being said. I don't see much benefit from this approach, as the JSON would be hard-coded too.

Edit: Actually I do see a benefit. This at least decouples your data source with the retrieval of data.

Comment: Beware, do some reading on asynchronous querying if you are unfamiliar with it. The getJSON function is asynchronous, which means the function which performs on the JSON, is not guaranteed to happen in a sequential fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Put your your products data in a global array:

```
<script>
  function product(name, code) {
     this.name = name;
     this.code = code;
  };
  var productArray = [ new product("Apple", "a"), new product("Orange", "o") ];

  // user array
  for (var i = 0; i < productArray.length; ++i)
     if (productArray[i].name == "Apple")
       console.log(productArray[i].code);
</script>
```

Comment: Well, as I said I'm new to JS (and scripting-languages in general), so who am I to judge.. But isn't there a more elegant way to accomplish this? The products are subject to change, and I don't think it's good style to force source code manipulations for such a thing.

Comment: @JacobS Yes, it can be change certainly. Because you need not to "hard code" the array, but instead write it using server side. What is the server language you're using? (php, asp.net, JSP...)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help - I'm going to use Helpful Lama's approach tho.